# Collect markdown headlines in vim?

Tags: vim, markdown

I am trying to come up with a TOC (table of contents) of a text document:
lines starting with # (hashtag) VIM would "collect" into the buffer or maybe place them at the TOP OF FILE.

(Or - other idea - erase all lines in a duplicate file NOT starting with a #)
There must be solutions to this question...

Comment: Is it necessary to use a plugin (e.g. https://github.com/wikimatze/tocdown )?

Comment: https://github.com/mzlogin/vim-markdown-toc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`:global`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#:global) command.

You can see all lines starting with `#` with `:g/^#/p`
and put them in a file using the `:redir` command :

```
:redir > toc.txt
:g/^#/p
:redir END
```

Note that `toc.txt` will contain the line numbers if you have `set number`. There is also [this post](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Redirect_g_search_output) on the subject.

Alternatively, you can delete all lines *not* starting with `#` with `:v` or `:g!` and save it to another file.

```
:v/\#/d
:w! toc.txt | undo
```

Look also for [`:copy`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#:copy) (`:t`) and [`:move`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#:move).

`:global` applies the command you provide to each matched lines in the order they appear in the file, so `:g/^#/t0` will copy headers to the top of the file but in reverse. We could do `:v/^#/m$` to move all non-header lines to the end, leaving the headers on top but stripped from the original text. Another way is to place some marker to mark the *end of the table of content* and copy header lines one line above this marker :

```
:g/^#/t?end-toc?-1
```

Comment: The t does not move the lines, it copies them

Comment: @perelo: The `redir` - solution works as I thought of. Line-Numbers help to find the marked lines! Great, thanks! PS: `redir` can also copy to a buffer (see vim help)